# How do I import functions from other folders in Python?

Tags: python, directory, path, relative-path

This is my folder structure:

```
-Test
      -Folder1
            -a.py
      -Folder2
            -test.py
      -b.py
```

where `a.py`:

```
def a():
    print('a works!')
```

and `b.py`:

```
def b():
    print('b works!')
```

How do I run functions `a()` and `b()` from `test.py`?

I have tried `from Folder1.a import a`, `from .Folder1.a import a` and many other variations.

Comment: See [This Stack-Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) for information.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) answer your question?

Comment: Unless `test.py` and `b.py` are together part of a single package, it's generally not a good sign if you need to reference a module that sits at a higher level than the module you're referencing it from. If everything starts to reference everything, you should consider the structure of your program and how you break it up. You *can* reference `b` from `test`, but you should consider if you *should*.

Comment: @Grismar Well, I am actually looking to reference `a` from `test` and was just curious about `b`.

Comment: You don’t import files from directories; you import *modules*, which you arrange to be on `sys.path`.  You can install your modules in a “global” path entry, or you can add a specific entry for your modules.  These are the answer to each of the hundreds of questions on this topic.